# lib32bz2-1.0 missing on 16.04

Tags: package-management, 16.04

I have tried installing this package (needed for android studio).

This is the error i'm getting

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

I have already tried:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
```

&

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0:i386
```

I also searched on http://packages.ubuntu.com and did not find `lib32bz2-1.0` for Ubuntu 16.04. So how do i get this package which is available for trusty and precise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The naming scheme `lib32bz2` suggest a very old-style way to manage the coexistence of multiple architectures on the same system. Use the package `libbz2-1.0:i386` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for 16.04 on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916379/unable-to-run-mksdcard-tool-during-android-studio-installation-on-ubuntu-15-04/39567843.

```
sudo apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```